# Change Tab Colour Based on Column Values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to change the tab colour of a sheet based on cell values that are generated within that same sheet (cell values are actually text showing when payments are due as you will see in my code below). All text values are generated through formulas within the cells "C6:C29".

I have written a code which works exactly for my requirements, **but only for cell "C6"** at the moment. When I try to change the "C6" in my code to "C6:C29", it no longer works (throws back errors).

Can anyone advise how I can expand my code to check the range of cells "C6:C29" rather than just the single cell "C6"?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Select Case Range("C6").Value
        Case "Due In 5 Days"
            Me.Tab.ColorIndex = 45
        Case "Due In 4 Days"
            Me.Tab.ColorIndex = 45
        Case "Due In 3 Days"
            Me.Tab.ColorIndex = 45
        Case "Due In 2 Days"
            Me.Tab.ColorIndex = 45
        Case "Due Tomorrow"
            Me.Tab.ColorIndex = 45
        Case "Due Today"
            Me.Tab.ColorIndex = 3
        Case Else
            Me.Tab.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    End Select
End Sub
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check C6:C29 for what? Do you want to change the tab's color 24 times every time a value on the worksheet changes?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! To clear things up, each row is a separate month so this month we are looking at cell C6 to tell me when the payment is due (I.e. in 5 days or 4 days or today etc etc). Next month cell C6 no longer matters (it’s in the past) and will become blank so we are now looking at cell C7 to show when the payment is due. The month after, C7 will also become blank and it will be C8 showing the due dates and so on. (follows on below.....)

Comment: There can only ever (at any time) be ONE of the cells in C6:C29 showing when the payment is due therefore I’m simply trying to search the whole range C6:C29 for any of the ‘Due in X Days’ text. When the text appears (it will depend on the date) i’d Like the tab to become orange for 5 days, 4 days, 3 days, 2 days and Tomorrow and the tab to turn red if payment is due Today. Hope that makes sense. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you would want something where: 
If there's at least one due today, make it ColorIndex = 3,
If there's at least one due in 5 days, but none due today, make it 45,
and if there's none due further out, make it the default color.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim daysLeft As Integer
    daysLeft = 100 'just a number larger than you need
    For i = 6 To 29
        Select Case Range("C" & i).Value
        Case "Due In 5 Days"
            If daysLeft >= 5 Then daysLeft = 5
        Case "Due In 4 Days"
            If daysLeft >= 4 Then daysLeft = 4
        Case "Due In 3 Days"
            If daysLeft >= 3 Then daysLeft = 3
        Case "Due In 2 Days"
            If daysLeft >= 2 Then daysLeft = 2
        Case "Due Tomorrow"
            If daysLeft >= 1 Then daysLeft = 1
        Case "Due Today"
            If daysLeft >= 0 Then daysLeft = 0
        End Select
    Next
    Select Case daysLeft
        Case 100
            Me.Tab.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
        Case 1 To 5
            Me.Tab.ColorIndex = 45
        Case 0
            Me.Tab.ColorIndex = 3
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! The code above works perfectly for "Due Tomorrow" and "Due Today" but not for "Due in 5 Days", 4 days, 3 days or 2 days. I can't think why. I've tested it on all of the cells C6:C29 and the above noted works/ does not work each time

Comment: @RabHillcrest This is a case-sensitive comparison. "Due in 5 Days" does not match "Due In 5 Days". That could be the reason

Comment: I've worked it out. It was simply that the word "Days" on my spreadsheet had no uppercase 'D', it had lowercase. When I changed it, it works fine. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Ah, same comment as me! Many thanks, I'm very grateful